# foreach (var in item) and exclusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, razor

Small Question,

I am having the following in my c# mvc project code:

```html
div class="card-body">
                @if (User.IsInRole("Secretaris"))
                {
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        if (User.IsInRole("Secretaris"))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.FirstName)</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }

                </table>
                }
            </div>
```

When I run the code everything works fine but when I go into the foreach it still gives all the names and not only the names that have the role "Secretaris". Hope someone can help me in what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Roel Knippen

Comment: What language/framework is this? Add some relevant tags to your question so the right people can find it.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Razor. Added language tag to help direct it.

Comment: I'm confused what your code wants to do. Are the "models" users? and you want to show which users have the role Secretaris?

Comment: `User.IsInRole` refers to the currently logged-in user, not any of your models.  The current user has that role.

Comment: What is the data type of `item`? Seems like you need to check that for the presence of the role. Does it have a property or method that you can use to check it?

Comment: Why do you need the second `if (User.IsInRole("Secretaris"))` inside your loop, when you've already evaluated that condition on the second line of code ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Model` has a `.Firstname` property I assume your model represents a person, likely a user.

`@User` represents the currently logged in user - NOT the user from your model.
You will need to include role information in your model if you want to work with users/permissions in your model.  Something like

```
if (modelItem.Roles.Contains("Sec...")) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the table to begin with, you check to see if the User has the Secretaris role. So it either will or will not show, depending on that role.

However, then within the foreach loop you check to see if the user is in that role again, which is redundant because that code won't even run if it's not due to your enclosing if statement.

I'm assuming you want to run some kind of check on the "item" object that is an element of the Model.

Answer (score 0):

```
div class="card-body">
            @if (User.IsInRole("Secretaris"))
            {
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (item.role == "Secretaris")
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.FirstName)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }

            </table>
            }
        </div>
```

Maybe something like this where you check if the item.role is secretaris?